# Linux Package "hardinfo" not showing all drives?

Tags: linux, hardware

I've called our data center to find out that we have 4 drives on the server. However when I ran "hardinfo" after installing it I am only seeing two drives.  Is it possible that two of them are not connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that they are managed by RAID controller and form two mirrored pairs?